# Invariant Violation: Tried to register two views with the same name RNCSafeAreaProvider

Tags: reactjs, react-native, yarnpkg, package.json, react-native-elements

I'm getting this strange error when I'm importing Overlay from 'react-native-elements'. So I've tried some solutions like deleting `yarn lock` file, removing `react-native-safe-area-context` from `package.lock` file and then deleting node_modules and running `yarn` but I'm still getting the same error. How can I fix that?

Comment: Did you find the solution yet?